# hibernate HQL join error

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to get my HQL query working but I've been stuck for a while now and decided to ask here.

I keep getting 'Path expected for join!'

So i have 2 tables that I would like to Query which i already have the SQL query for.

these are my xml mappings

```
Kamer.hbm.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="model.Kamer" table="kamer">
    <id name="kamerid">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="hotelid"/>
    <property name="kamertypeid" />
    <property name="status"      />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>


Reservatie.hbm.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="model.Reservatie" table="reservatie">
    <id name="reservatieID">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="klantID"/>
    <property name="kamertypeID" />
    <many-to-one name="kamerID" class="model.Kamer" />
    <property name="hotelID"      />
    <property name="verblijfsformuleID"  />
    <property name="verblijfsperiodeID"    />
    <property name="betalingsID" />
    <property name="gastID"     />
    <property name="kredietkaartID"/>
    <property name="start_datum"      />
    <property name="eind_datum"   />
    <property name="reservatie_datum"   />
    <property name="tijdige_annulatie"   />
    <property name="check_in_datum"   />
    <property name="check_uit_datum"   />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

these are my 2 java classes

```
package model;

public class Kamer {

public int kamerid;
public int hotelid;
public int kamertypeid;
public String status;

public Kamer() {
}

public Kamer(int kamerid, int hotelid, int kamertypeid, String status) {
    this.kamerid = kamerid;
    this.hotelid = hotelid;
    this.kamertypeid = kamertypeid;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getKamerid() {
    return kamerid;
}

public void setKamerid(int kamerid) {
    this.kamerid = kamerid;
}

public int getHotelid() {
    return hotelid;
}

public void setHotelid(int hotelid) {
    this.hotelid = hotelid;
}

public int getKamertypeid() {
    return kamertypeid;
}

public void setKamertypeid(int kamertypeid) {
    this.kamertypeid = kamertypeid;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Kamer{" +
            "kamerid=" + kamerid +
            ", hotelid=" + hotelid +
            ", kamertypeid=" + kamertypeid +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

and

```
package model;
import java.util.Date;

public class Reservatie {

public int reservatieID;
public int klantID;
public int kamertypeID;
public int kamerID;
public int hotelID;
public int verblijfsformuleID;
public int verblijfsperiodeID;
public int betalingsID;
public int gastID;
public int kredietkaartID;
public Date start_datum;
public Date eind_datum;
public Date reservatie_datum;
public String tijdige_annulatie;
public Date check_in_datum;
public Date check_uit_datum;


public Reservatie() { }

public Reservatie(int reservatieID,int klantID, int kamertypeID, int kamerID, int hotelID,       int verblijfsformuleID, int verblijfsperiodeID, int betalingsID, int gastID, int kredietkaartID, Date start_datum, Date eind_datum, Date reservatie_datum, String tijdige_annulatie, Date check_in_datum, Date check_uit_datum) {
    this.reservatieID = reservatieID;
    this.klantID = klantID;
    this.kamertypeID = kamertypeID;
    this.kamerID = kamerID;
    this.hotelID = hotelID;
    this.verblijfsformuleID = verblijfsformuleID;
    this.verblijfsperiodeID = verblijfsperiodeID;
    this.betalingsID = betalingsID;
    this.gastID = gastID;
    this.kredietkaartID = kredietkaartID;
    this.start_datum = start_datum;
    this.eind_datum = eind_datum;
    this.reservatie_datum = reservatie_datum;
    this.tijdige_annulatie = tijdige_annulatie;
    this.check_in_datum = check_in_datum;
    this.check_uit_datum = check_uit_datum;
}

public int getKlantID() {
    return klantID;
}

public void setKlantID(int klantID) {
    this.klantID = klantID;
}

public int getReservatieID() {
    return reservatieID;
}

public void setReservatieID(int reservatieID) {
    this.reservatieID = reservatieID;
}

public int getKamertypeID() {
    return kamertypeID;
}

public void setKamertypeID(int kamertypeID) {
    this.kamertypeID = kamertypeID;
}

public int getKamerID() {
    return kamerID;
}

public void setKamerID(int kamerID) {
    this.kamerID = kamerID;
}

public int getHotelID() {
    return hotelID;
}

public void setHotelID(int hotelID) {
    this.hotelID = hotelID;
}

public int getVerblijfsformuleID() {
    return verblijfsformuleID;
}

public void setVerblijfsformuleID(int verblijfsformuleID) {
    this.verblijfsformuleID = verblijfsformuleID;
}

public int getVerblijfsperiodeID() {
    return verblijfsperiodeID;
}

public void setVerblijfsperiodeID(int verblijfsperiodeID) {
    this.verblijfsperiodeID = verblijfsperiodeID;
}

public int getBetalingsID() {
    return betalingsID;
}

public void setBetalingsID(int betalingsID) {
    this.betalingsID = betalingsID;
}

public int getGastID() {
    return gastID;
}

public void setGastID(int gastID) {
    this.gastID = gastID;
}

public int getKredietkaartID() {
    return kredietkaartID;
}

public void setKredietkaartID(int kredietkaartID) {
    this.kredietkaartID = kredietkaartID;
}

public Date getStart_datum() {
    return start_datum;
}

public void setStart_datum(Date start_datum) {
    this.start_datum = start_datum;
}

public Date getEind_datum() {
    return eind_datum;
}

public void setEind_datum(Date eind_datum) {
    this.eind_datum = eind_datum;
}

public Date getReservatie_datum() {
    return reservatie_datum;
}

public void setReservatie_datum(Date reservatie_datum) {
    this.reservatie_datum = reservatie_datum;
}

public String getTijdige_annulatie() {
    return tijdige_annulatie;
}

public void setTijdige_annulatie(String tijdige_annulatie) {
    this.tijdige_annulatie = tijdige_annulatie;
}

public Date getCheck_in_datum() {
    return check_in_datum;
}

public void setCheck_in_datum(Date check_in_datum) {
    this.check_in_datum = check_in_datum;
}

public Date getCheck_uit_datum() {
    return check_uit_datum;
}

public void setCheck_uit_datum(Date check_uit_datum) {
    this.check_uit_datum = check_uit_datum;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Reservatie{" +
            "reservatieID=" + reservatieID +
            ", klantID=" + klantID +
            ", kamertypeID=" + kamertypeID +
            ", kamerID=" + kamerID +
            ", hotelID=" + hotelID +
            ", verblijfsformuleID=" + verblijfsformuleID +
            ", verblijfsperiodeID=" + verblijfsperiodeID +
            ", betalingsID=" + betalingsID +
            ", gastID=" + gastID +
            ", kredietkaartID=" + kredietkaartID +
            ", start_datum=" + start_datum +
            ", eind_datum=" + eind_datum +
            ", reservatie_datum=" + reservatie_datum +
            ", tijdige_annulatie='" + tijdige_annulatie + '\'' +
            ", check_in_datum=" + check_in_datum +
            ", check_uit_datum=" + check_uit_datum +
            '}';
}
}
```

and here is my HQL part

```
import model.Reservatie;
import org.hibernate.Query; 
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import persistentie.HibernateUtil;
import model.Kamer;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


@SuppressWarnings({"ALL"})
public class testKamer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();


    String HQL_QUERY = "SELECT k FROM Kamer k LEFT JOIN Reservatie r with k.kamerid = r.kamerID";
    Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);
    List result = query.list();
    for(Iterator it = result.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
        Kamer kamer = (Kamer) it.next();
        System.out.println("Kamer: "+kamer.kamerid);
    }
}
}
```

also here is the original SQL Query

```
     SELECT *
     FROM kamer
     LEFT JOIN reservatie
     ON kamer.kamerid=reservatie.kamerid and kamer.kamertypeid = reservatie.kamertypeid and kamer.hotelid = reservatie.hotelid
     where not reservatie.verblijfsperiodeid = 2 or reservatie.kamerid is null;
```

any help is welcome, 
thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the exact problem? :S

Comment: sorry totally forgot to mention that, it's late over here. I keep getting "Path expected for join!"

Comment: a stack trace with the relevant sources would be helpful I guess

Comment: The problem is not (just) with the HQL. The problem is that you don't have any association between your entities. You store IDs of other entities instead of storing references to them. Read Hibernate's documentation about associations, and start using them, because joins are only possible with associations.

Comment: So both my xml mappings are wrong you are saying ? I'm fairly new to all this stuff so I thought by adding the many-to-one property in the kamer.hbm.xml  I made the association ? Do you think you can highlight where the problem is so I can search more specific?  thanks in advance !

Comment: on which line you are getting error now ?

Comment: on this line in Testkamer.java:     Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);

Comment: You have not understood what an association is. The `Reservatie` class should have a field `kamer` of type `Kamer`. Not a field `kamerID` of type `int`. I won't explain how to create and map such an association, because the Hibernate documentation does it already. Read the documentation.

Comment: Oh thanks, so basicly I need to make an assocation in my java class and then I need to remake my mapping. I'm gonna give that a try later when I get home, big thanks !

Comment: ok I just got home and adapted  my mapping and java class and it all works now with the right join query given before! thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Your Query should be

```
String HQL_QUERY = "SELECT k FROM reservatie r right join Kamer k";
```

or

```
String HQL_QUERY = "SELECT k FROM reservatie r join Kamer k";
```

Comment: sadly enough that doesn't work and gives the same error, this being:    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT k FROM model.Kamer k LEFT JOIN reservatie r with k.kamerid = r.kamerID]